# Spring deserialize a json dynamically can either be List or just an Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, deserialization

I create sample class and response to deserialized but this is same issue that need to be fix. The response can either be Array with Object or `just an Object`.
Need to deserialized dynamically

Class

```
public record  MainClass(
  //the response can either be array or not array
  @JsonProperty("Relation") List<Relation> relation
){

 
}


public record  Relation(
   String relation,
   String Id,
){

 
}
```

Deserialize when if response is array `Working`

Response

```
{
 "Relation": [
          {
            "url": "https://sample.com",
            "Id": "77"
          }
        ]
        
}
```

Deserialize when if response NOT array
`This need to be fix`

Response

```
{
 "Relation":{
            "url": "https://sample.com",
            "Id": "77"
          }
        
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to provide two setters for the property.

```java
public class RelationWrapper
   private String id;
   private List<Relation> relation;

   public void setRelation(Relation relation) {
      this.relation = relation == null ? null : List.of(relation);
   }

   public void setRelation(List<Relation> relation) {
      this.relation = relation;
   }

   public List<Relation> getRelation() {
      return relation;
   }
}
```

This could also be done with two constructors

```java
public class RelationWrapper
   private final String id;
   private final List<Relation> relation;

   @ConstructorProperties({"id", "relation"})
   public RelationWrapper(String id, List<Relation> relation) {
      this.id = id;
      this.relation = relation;
   }

   @ConstructorProperties({"id", "relation"})
   public RelationWrapper(String id, Relation relation) {
      this.id = id;
      this.relation = relation == null ? null : List.of(relation);
   }

   // getters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to use `JsonNode` to represent the value since that can represent any value (number, string, array or object)

```
public class RelationWrapper {
   private String id;
   private JsonNode relation;

   // getters & setters
}

public class Relation {
   private String id;
   private String url;

   // getters & setters
}
```

```
public class MyService {
   private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

   public void doStuffWithJson(String json) {
      RelationWrapper wrapper = objectMapper.readValue(json, RelationWrapper.class);
      JsonNode relation = wrapper.getRelation();
      Relation[] relations;
      if (relation.isNull()) {
         relations = null;
      } else if (relation.isArray()) {
         objectMapper.treeToValue(relation, Relation[].class);
      } else {
         relations = new Relation[] { objectMapper.treeToValue(relation, Relation.class) };
      }
      doStuff(wrapper, relations);
   }
}
```

See

- [ObjectMapper.valueToTree(Object)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#valueToTree(java.lang.Object))
- [ObjectMapper.treeToValue(TreeNode, Class)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode,%20java.lang.Class))
- [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should write custom std deserializer, First of all modify your wrappers to handle both

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RelationContainer {
  
  private Relation relation;
  private List<Relation> relations;
}
```

Then Create custom std deserializer:

```
public class RelationStdDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<RelationContainer> {
  
  public RelationStdDeserializer() {
    super(RelationContainer.class);
  }

  @Override
  public RelationContainer deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    var objectCodec = jsonParser.getCodec();
    var jsonTree = objectCodec.readTree(jsonParser);
    if(jsonTree instanceof NullNode){
      return null;
    } else if (jsonTree instanceof ObjectNode objectNode) {
      var relationNode = objectNode.get("relations");
      if(relationNode instanceof NullNode){
        return new RelationContainer(null, null);
      } else if (relationNode instanceof ObjectNode jsonObject) {
        var relation = traverseNode(jsonObject, objectCodec, new TypeReference<Relation>() {
        });
        return new RelationContainer(relation, null);
      } else if (relationNode instanceof ArrayNode arrayObject) {
        var relations = traverseNode(arrayObject, objectCodec, new TypeReference<List<Relation>>() {
        });
        return new RelationContainer(null, relations);
      }
    }
    throw new IOException("Failed to read relations");
  }
  
  private <T> T traverseNode(JsonNode jsonNode, ObjectCodec objectCodec, TypeReference<T> typeReference) throws IOException {
    try(var jsonParser = jsonNode.traverse(objectCodec)){
      return objectCodec.readValue(jsonParser, typeReference);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally register deserializer in object mapper bean:

```
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    var relationModule = new SimpleModule();
    relationModule.addDeserializer(RelationContainer.class, new RelationStdDeserializer());
    return objectMapper;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is a common one when dealing with JSON data in Java, especially when the structure of the JSON is not consistent. In your case, the "Relation" field can either be a JSON array or a single JSON object. This inconsistency poses a challenge for deserialization.

Your current approach, using Jackson's `@JsonProperty` annotation, is on the right track, but it needs to be adapted to handle the variability in the JSON structure. Here's a state-of-the-art approach to handle this situation:

First) **Type Reference with Generics:** You can use Jackson's TypeReference with generics to handle this. For example, you could try deserializing to List and if it fails (due to a `JsonProcessingException`), try again with just Relation.

Then) **Optional Wrappers:** In some cases, using Java's Optional class as a wrapper around your object might help in handling the nullability and presence of the JSON fields.

#### Step 1: Create the Wrapper Class

```
public class RelationWrapper {

    private Optional<List<Relation>> relationsList;
    private Optional<Relation> singleRelation;

    public RelationWrapper(List<Relation> relationsList) {
        this.relationsList = Optional.ofNullable(relationsList);
        this.singleRelation = Optional.empty();
    }

    public RelationWrapper(Relation singleRelation) {
        this.singleRelation = Optional.ofNullable(singleRelation);
        this.relationsList = Optional.empty();
    }

    // Getters
    // Setter
}
```

#### Step 2: Implement Custom Deserializer

```
public class RelationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<RelationWrapper> {
    
    @Override
    public RelationWrapper deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        try {
            // Attempt to deserialize as List<Relation>
            List<Relation> relations = jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(node, new TypeReference<List<Relation>>() {});
            return new RelationWrapper(relations);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // If it fails, deserialize as a single Relation object
            Relation relation = jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(node, Relation.class);
            return new RelationWrapper(relation);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Final step: Using the Custom Deserializer

Finally, you need to tell Jackson to use this custom deserializer when deserializing the Relation field. You can do this by annotating the Relation field in your MainClass with `@JsonDeserialize`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MainClass {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = RelationDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("Relation")
    private RelationWrapper relation;

    // Constructor, getters, and setters
    public MainClass(RelationWrapper relation) {
        this.relation = relation;
    }

    public RelationWrapper getRelation() {
        return relation;
    }
}
```

This solution provides a flexible and elegant way to deserialize JSON where the structure of a specific field can vary. The Optional wrappers in RelationWrapper make it clear and easy to check whether you have a list of relations or a single relation.